# What does "sácala pues" mean to someone in Mexico?

Tags: méxico

What does "sácala pues" mean to someone in Mexico?
Is it slang for how's it hanging? Or how's it going?

Comment: More context is needed. No, it is not how's it hanging. It's **imperative**.

Answer (score 4):

It's not "saca la pues", it is "sácala", that literally translates to "bring it out".

This can be used literally to bring something out or also as a rude way to challenge someone, normally referring to a gun or anything referred to someone's manhood, I think you can guess what it means.

The "pues" is something like a "come on" used to urge someone to do something.

Comment: Is it sexual in nature or more a challenge to fight?

Comment: in the rude way, it can be used in sexual nature,  in the non-rude way it is totally neutral,